# Fetch all values from a hash which has large volumes of key value pairs

Tags: redis

Can anyone help me to find a way to fetch all values from a hash(name:VALUE) in redis which contains large number of key value pairs(having names:VALUE:10 etc)[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HGETALL](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall) to get all the key value pairs .But i am curious to know why you want this?

Hope it helps!

Comment: [`HVALS`](http://redis.io/commands/hvals) is even more fitting, but the question remains - why would Smith want to do that? ;)

Comment: My intention is to dispaly all the key value pairs in VALUE in a gridview control of my web application.I am trying to do a select query similar to SQL.I need to display all the fields in keys ranging from VALUE:10 to VALUE:1002.Is there any way to do this out.Each line of my grid should be fileds of keys (whose hash value is from VALUE:10 to VALUE:1002)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a use case where you want to get the products of java with this price range you can do this via.

```
         jedis.zadd("JAVA_Product",100,"PID1");
         jedis.zadd("JAVA_Product",10,"PID2");
         jedis.zadd("JAVA_Product",11,"PID4");
         jedis.zadd("JAVA_Product",1200,"PID3");


         Set<String> rangeofProducts = jedis.zrangeByScore("JAVA_Product", 10,100);
         rangeofProducts.forEach(System.out::println);
```

It will print all the products with price between 10 and 100.

Hope it helps!.